# How I debug a mongodb slow regex query?

Tags: mongodb

I have two simple queries on a collection of 22 millions documents.

query 1:

```
db.audits.find({"w.em": /^name.lastname/i})
```

return in less than 1 second.

query 2:

```
db.audits.find({"w.d": /^name.lastname/i})
```

it runs for more than 30seconds (and rightly not found results).

The only difference on the two queries is the field I am searching on. Both fields are indexed, [you can find here the `explain` for both](https://www.diffchecker.com/zVDWY822) : it is identical!

[Here  the explains with `executionStats`](https://www.diffchecker.com/apfpD6B7)

How can the queries perform so differently??

I am on mongodb `3.4.23`

Comment: can you post the output of `.explain("executionStats")` and some sample documents from the collection?

Comment: Post the entire output I need to check how many documents it has to go through for both the queries. Your query also depends a lot on what kind of index you are using.

Comment: @VishalTyagi in the link you find the full output, what do you need more? So I can provide it! thanks!

Comment: @JoeDrumgoole here the complete with executionStats https://www.diffchecker.com/apfpD6B7

Comment: Did you run both queries multiple times to get consistent times? Based on # of docs examined, it looks like you ran query 2 & then query 1; could the difference be that the second time you ran a query the docs were already in memory? The execution stats do look the same

Comment: @willis thanks but is not the case. Even if I change the order of the query the first one (the one on w.em is always pretty fast) and the other one is extremely slow... also, the times are constant on multiple runs

Comment: Huh. One other thing that looks strange about your explains is that the `executionTimeMillis` for both in the executionStats is roughly the same (18 seconds). How sure are you that your instrumentation for the query speed is correct?

Comment: @willis I am running them manullay from the mongoshell. You are right anyway... do Mongo start returning results before completing the query? That would explain my wrong assumption on time. Because the query that I see fast return instantly with (press ty to load more) and the other return no results

Comment: Yes, when you run a query in the shell, mongo will return a cursor. You can then iterate through that cursor to get all of the results. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/